# A name for the inverse image of the center of a quotient group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, quandles

Given the projection $\pi_A$ from a group $G$ to $G/A$ where $A$ is normal, is there a name and/or a standard notation for $\pi_A^{-1}\left(Z\left(G/A\right)\right)$?

I came across this object in my studies of racks and I wondered if it had been already named in the literature but I couldn't find any easy reference.

Comment: Without a name, the notation $Z(G mod A)$ is used by A. Mann in "Elements of minimal breadth...", J. Aust. Math. Soc. 81 (2006).

Comment: I don't think it has a special name, except in the special case where $A=Z(G)$ (in which case you have the "second center", $Z_2(G)$), or more generally, obtained by such an iteration, producing the upper central series of $G$, $Z(G)=Z_1(G)\leq Z_2(G)\leq Z_3(G)\leq\cdots$.

Comment: I think this is the occasion to ask specialists to suggest a nice name and notation.

Comment: How about "precenter"?

Comment: @Giuliano: I doubt that a name exists, since the concept depends not just on $G$ but also on which normal subgroup $A$ you work with.   (Small side note: a letter like $H$ or $N$ might be better, not suggesting "abelian" as the letter $A$ does.  Unless that special case is what you have in mind.)

Comment: If you do a google search for *preimage of the center* you'll get a gajillion hits. So maybe go with that?

Comment: @ Jim Humphreys : There is some concepts depending on G and a subgroup, which in fact have names, for instance "centralizer" and "normalizer".

Answer (score 1):

Since, there seem not to be an accepted term, I hereby propose, accepting the suggestion of Prof. Agol

**Definition**. Given a surjective morphism of groups $f:G \rightarrow H $ the preimage of the center of $H$ shall be the **precenter** of $f$ and shall be indicated by $Z^{-1} \left( f \right)$.

The case proposed in my question would became $ Z^{-1}\left( \pi_A \right)$.

The jury is out :-)

Comment: To my mind, it is better to find a notation that does not refer to any homomorphism, only to the subgroup and the whole group.

Comment: @YassineGuerboussa Make your proposal then!
The sense of mine was to be somewhat categorical, the morphisms and not the objects are the heroes...

Comment: I suggest $Z_G(N)$, $N$ normal in $G$, and I would call it the center of $G$ modulo $N$.  The precenter of $f$ is the center of $G$ modulo $ker(f)$, for brevity $Z_G(f)$ (or $Z(f)$).  (Is it  useful to see Group Theory from a categorical aspect?). Sincerely.

Comment: That's the notation for centralizer of N in G.

Answer (score 1):

Baer in Representations of groups as quotient groups. I. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 58, (1945) defines the notion of *commutator quotient* (and he says that he takes it from Zassenhaus): if S,T are subsets of a group G he defines:

$$ S \div T = \lbrace g \in G | [T, g] \subseteq S \rbrace $$

With this notation you have

$$ Z\left( \frac{G}{N} \right) = \frac{N \div G}{N}$$